# d3js Dateformat: Hours, Minutes and Seconds incorrect

Tags: datetime, d3.js, charts, date-format

i have chart made with d3js( **V7** ).
It displays the Date correct but not the time.

I get "2023-02-01 01:00:00" for `new Date('2023-02-01 09:00:00')`

My Dateformat:
`d3.axisBottom( d3.scaleUtc().domain([this.minXValue, this.maxXValue]).range([this.currentElementOptions.margin.left, this.xAxisWidth]) ).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'));`

I should get "2023-02-01 09:00:00" and not "2023-02-01 01:00:00"

What am i doing wrong/missing?

Comment: Is your time zone +8 hrs from UTC?

Comment: I'm not displaying the current date but a static value. The timezone should not matter. It should just format the date string